# sharing images in objects with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have one original object **post.rb** with the next fields or attributes.

```
class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 mount_uploader :posted, PostedUploader, mount_on: :posted_filename
 field :posted
 field :remote_posted_url

 attr_accessible :posted, :remote_posted_url
end
```

Then I want create a copy from the first original object and share images for the new object. Then I doing:

```
attribs = @post.attributes.select {|a| %w(posted remote_posted_url).include? a }
new_post = Post.new attribs
new_post.save
```

So far, everything works fine the new object, share the images of the original. The two objects have the same shared image with the same path.

**The problem is if I delete the original object, the clone object can not find the image because I deleted in original post.**

How can I, in my destroy action object, with a callback **before_destroy**, **check whether the image is used by one or more objects**.

if the image, using 2 or more objects,

#### Not delete the image.

otherwise, if the image is used by a single object,

#### Delete the image.

Its possible?

I'm need a method to verify this problem.

Comment: Hi, can you share your Gemfile and PostedUploader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `remove_posted` callback injected by CW in your model:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :posted, PostedUploader, mount_on: :posted_filename
  field :posted
  field :remote_posted_url

  attr_accessible :posted, :remote_posted_url

  # override as to not delete if there's another model storing the same image
  def remove_posted!
    super unless Post.where(posted_filename: posted_filename).count > 1
  end
end
```

PS: `Post.new(attribs).save` should be copying the file, not use the same one, maybe you ought to assign a File.open(path) to the posted column insted of the uploader.

Comment: Can you say me how assign a File.open(path) in one example :D. Thank you clyfe!

Comment: I get other fix that works fine also. `def remove!
   if !model.class.where(:posted_filename => model.posted_filename).first
     super
   end
  end`